# find the data from the last line

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a database that updates regularly by creating a new line on my sheet.
I want to create a script that saves the last line of the sheet as an email in a Gmail label.

I started this code, how to have the data of the "lastrow" , ligne.getValue don't work.

```
function laroyale(){

var feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var ligne   = feuille.getLastRow();
var data    = ligne.getValue ();
```

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data

Comment: yes I read but I still do not understand, I can not make the command: lastRow.getValue


I'm french and there is really not much info in my language

Comment: A row is a number - a primitive with no methods. It is not a `Sheet` (feuille) nor is it a `Range`, each of which has methods (such as `getLastRow()` or `getValues()`).

Comment: ok, so I'll find out how to create the .getLastrange method because it does not exist;)

Comment: Consider `Sheet#getSheetValues` and then review how to access values in an array of arrays (`Object[][]`)

Comment: Try feuille.getRange(feuille.getLastRow(),1,1,feuille.getLastColumn().getValues();  which means sheet.getRange(row,column,num rows,num columns).getValues();  This will return a 2D array which, using your requirements, would be data[0] is the one and only row, data[0][0] would be the cell corresponding to the first column of that row.

Comment: ok, I succeeded thanks to you.                                                                                                      
  var feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data    = feuille.getRange(feuille.getLastRow(),1,1,feuille.getLastColumn()).getValues();